# Combine Inheritance and Composition - Design Pattern

Tags: java, design-patterns

Sorry for the unclear Title.
I have a following scenario:

I have 4 types: **Type1, Type2, Type3, Type4**. (which have same structure: *name* and *children*)

I have other 4 types of children: **Child1, Child2, Child3, Child4.** (which in turn have the same structure: *parent* and *value*).

**Condition**: Type1 can have only children of type: Child1; Type2->child2 and so on.

If I use Inheritance for this case: all of types inheritate from SuperType and all of children inheritate from Children.

```
public class Children {

}

public class SuperType {
    private List<Children> children;
}

public class Type1 extends SuperType {

}

public class Child1 extends Children {

}
```

Type1 can have children from Child2, Child3, Child4. That's not what I want.

Do you have any idea about pattern designs which I could use for this case?

Comment: a parentclass should have/has no impact on which classes it may extend. a parent class shouldn't even be aware a(ny) childclass exists

Comment: @Stultuske: and you think Inheritance in this case is not a proper approach?

Comment: you say: Type1 can HAVE children ... that points to composition, rather than inheritance. composition is a HAS A relationship, inheritance is an IS A relationship

Comment: That's right. But all of types are the same structure, all of children are the same structure. That's why I would like to use the inheritance approach.

Comment: teacher and student are the same structure as well, yet a teacher has students, and students have a teacher. being a student doesn't make one a teacher

Comment: This  time I don't agree. Your example is not the same with my case.

Comment: and how are we to know? we know nothing of your case.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can solve it by making `SuperType` generic and using a type parameter for `Children`:

```
public class SuperType<T extends Children> {
    private List<T> children;
}
```

And then subclasses will specify their own type of `Children`:

```
public class Type1 extends SupperType<Child1>{}
public class Type2 extends SupperType<Child2>{}
```

All you'll have to do then is make the API of `SuperType` use the type parameter.